# How to display json array elements (with nested objects) dynamically into select tag?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have an array given by python:

```
[{u'boo': [u'var1', u'var2', u'var3', u'var4']}, u'Happines', u'May', u'Abecedary'
```

The array currently auto-fills the following way

```
<select>
   %for type in array:
      <option value="{{type}}">{{type}}</option>
   %end
</select>
```

While this work showing each single string with a correct value in the select, it fails with the object `{u'boo': [u'var1', u'var2', u'var3', u'var4']}`. It currently shows it all as a simple string. This is reasonable, the system wasn't made having this in mind, so I have the following question:

How can I make the system so that it display the key of the object (let's say example2), and displays a new select with all the new option belonging to such key?

So, if the user selects boo, a new select displaying `var1`, `var2`, `var3`,  and `var4` should appear.

Comment: It's super wierd that you have a dictionary with the same key twice. It's not supposed to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the data type of the element in the array using [**typeof**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), for example:

```
let arr = [{u'boo': [u'var1', u'var2', u'var3', u'var4']}, u'Happines', u'May', u'Abecedary'];

for(let i = 0; i < arr; i++) {
  // Checking if an element in arr is an object.
  if(typeof arr[i] === 'object') {
    let obj = arr[i];
    // Iterating the object using for-in loop.
    for(let prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(elem)) {
        // Do your object manipulation in here.
        console.log(obj.prop);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That way you always ensure that objects are taken into account. You can do the same for other data types which you expect to receive from python.

Comment: While I found that this answer must be correct, I'm afraid that I have a problem with it being in ES6, to parse it to 5 I should simply change let for var, right?

Comment: @JavierBullrich correct, for your projects I highly suggest that you move onto ES6 and use a tool like babelify to convert your ES6 into ES5 for you on compile time. Also if my answer is correct please click on the ckeckmark to accept it, and/or if it is helpful press up on the button to mark it as such. It is to let others know that you found the answer you needed and they can reference it on their own projects.